# Python bitwise & giving incorrect result

Tags: python, python-3.x, bitwise-and

Following is my code, the output of expression d is incorrect. It is returning True where as it should have returned False, as all the components in the expression evaluates to False.

When I am executing all component expression separately and executing the final expression by collating the result, the output is correct i.e. False

```
a = 0
b = 0
c = 1

d = (a == 1 or b == 1) & c == 0
print("(a == 1 or b == 1) & c == 0 : ",d)


f = (a == 1 or b == 1)
print("(a == 1 or b == 1) : ",f)
g = c == 0
print("c == 0 : ",g)

print("f&g : ",f&g)
```

OUTPUT:

```
(a == 1 or b == 1) & c == 0 :  True  #This is incorrect result
(a == 1 or b == 1) :  False
c == 0 :  False
f&g :  False
```

Can you please help in understanding this behaviour of Python code.

Comment: You should pay attention to the precedence of the operators. In your example, `(a == 1 or b == 1) & c ` is computed first, while you might be thinking that `c == 0` is computed first.

Answer (score 1):

The bitwise operators have higher precedence than comparison operators. So

```
(a == 1 or b == 1) & c == 0
```

is treated as

```
((a == 1 or b == 1) & c) == 0
```

To get what you want, you need to add parentheses

```
(a == 1 or b == 1) & (c == 0)
```

See the [operator precedence table](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)